What's wrong with my filter?
I'm working with the following script, created for an SQL-Server database:
DECLARE @TraceID INT;
DECLARE @MaxFileSize BIGINT = 50; -- File size limit in MB
DECLARE @TraceFilePath NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\Temp_Folder\SQLTraces\Trace_OrderPart10'; -- Base trace file path

-- Step 1: Create a new trace
EXEC sp_trace_create 
    @traceid = @TraceID OUTPUT,
    @options = 2, -- File rollover enabled
    @tracefile = @TraceFilePath,
    @maxfilesize = @MaxFileSize,
    @stoptime = NULL; -- No automatic stop


-- Step 2: Set events to capture
-- Add events to monitor SQL statements and related information
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData2

-- Step 3: Set a filter for the table CommandOrderParts
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 0, 6, N'VehicleOrderPart'; -- ObjectName filter

-- Optional: Output TraceID for reference
SELECT @TraceID AS TraceID;

-- Step 4: Start the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1; -- Start the trace

-- Step 5: Stop the trace
-- EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0; -- Stop the trace
-- EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2; -- Stop the trace

The most important question is: when I look at the corresponding trace file, I see (amongst many others) the following SQL queries:
SELECT TOP (2147483647) [Type],[Reserved],[PickSequence],[PickEnabled], ...
  FROM [database_name].[dbo].[Locations]

This gives me the impression that the next line is not taken into account:
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 0, 6, N'VehicleOrderPart'; -- ObjectName filter

As you can imagine, I would like to launch a trace on the actions on the [dbo].[VehicleOrderParts] table.
How can I achieve that?
Second question (optional): I'm launching this script, not from SQL Server Profiler, but from SQL-Server Management Studio. As a result, the second time I try to run the script, this fails as the script wants to create the file C:\Temp_Folder\SQLTraces\Trace_OrderPart10.trc, which already exists.
For your information:

The query SELECT @@VERSION (might be important for the definitions of the trace events and filter) has the following result:


Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5046861) - 16.0.1135.2 (X64)   Oct 18 2024 15:31:58   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor)


The query SELECT @@VERSION (...) has the following result on the computer where I wish to deploy it:


Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5029376) - 14.0.3465.1 (X64)
Jul 30 2023 15:31:58
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Can anybody help me out here?
Thanks in advance

Your filter uses N'VehicleOrderPart' but the table name is VehicleOrderParts as you mention, with an S at the end. Could it be a typo causing the problem? Also, could you try the filter as  N'%VehicleOrderPart%'?
Disclaimer: Not the downvoter.

@Ronaldo: sorry for my ranting comment and thanks for your quick reply. I've tried using the percentage signs but that did not solve the issue. I hope the whole thing is not case-sensitive? When I ask this question to ChatGPT, it keeps telling me to use 10 instead of 34 in the filtering definition, but as far as I understand, 10 is the eventId while the filtering mechanism is based on columnId. Do you have an idea?

In the meantime I had a proposal of ChatGPT again: it proposed to filter on TextData, leading to this filtering definition: exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 6, N'%VehicleOrderPart%'; -- TextData filter. This looks as if it works, but it makes me fear that the filtering is just applied on the display mechanism. Let me explain: my customer is using its database, and something goes wrong while working with VehicleOrderParts. So I'd like to investigate this (hence the stored procedure script). However I only want my script to perform any action when VehicleOrderParts are involved ...

... and I have the impression that my script acts on every object in database (which might have a huge impact on performance). Is there a way to say that the events only need to be logged in certain conditions? (Or is this what I'm actually doing?)

Since you're concerned about performance, maybe a better approach would be using Extended Events. Have you considered using it? Unfortunately, I've never created a trace using T-SQL, but I noticed you can generate the T-SQL script for a trace using Profiler: File > Export > Script Trace Definition > For SQL Server ....  You could try using the Profiler GUI to learn what's wrong with your code.

@Ronaldo: so there is "XEvent Profiler", "Extended Events" in the "Management" Object Explorer, "SQL Server Profiler" in the Tools menu, ..., how many profilers can a database system have? :-) As you've indeed understood, I'd like to monitor everything happening with one particular table. What profiler is best for this purpose? (I thought "XEvent Profiler" was too elaborated: it produces thousands of lines of output in some seconds, which is the reason I started experimenting with the sp_trace profiler.)

@Ronaldo: some background on my question: I wanted to do some profiling but XEvent Profiler produces far too much information, so I asked ChatGPT what to do. The thing gave me a script but at that time I didn't even know about SQL-Server Profiling. Only after having acquired some experience, working with the "sp_" related script, I realised that I could generate it automatically using the SQL-Server Profiler, hence my question here.

The goal is to find a problem which occurs once every few days, so running the trace session for a week should be realistic.
